# JDBC preparedStatement.executeUpdate and no changes in db (duplicate kyes)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following code:

```
for (Buddy buddy : buddyList.getBuddies())
{

int friendId = Integer.parseInt(buddyId); //this is valid btw always

preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("insert into members_friends "
                    + "(id_memb_friend1, id_memb_friend2, active) values (?, ?, ?) "
                    + "on duplicate key update id_memb_friend1 = values(id_memb_friend1), "
                    + "id_memb_friend2 = values(id_memb_friend2), "
                    + "id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");
            // parameters start with 1
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, Math.min(userId,friendId)); //sort it a bit
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, Math.max(userId,friendId));
            preparedStatement.setInt(3, 1); //active friendship

}
        try{
          //run prepared statement and add all them to database
          int returnValue = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }
catch(Exception e){
//I print exception here to file
}
```

What's going to happen here is that exception is not triggered but there are no any changes in database (for example new buddy is not added, nothing is changed). And returnValue = 1
In case that I use just insert without on duplicate key update I will get an error that key already exists in database.

My table if metters has the following indexes/keys:

**index: unique_friend_index**

Definition:
Type
BTREE
Unique
Yes
Columns
id_memb_friend1 id_memb_friend2

**Index: PRIMARY**

Definition:
Type
BTREE
Unique
Yes
Columns
id

**Index: id_memb_friend1**

Definition:
Type
BTREE
Unique
No
Columns
id_memb_friend1

**Index: id_memb_friend2**

Definition:
Type
BTREE
Unique
No
Columns
id_memb_friend2

I really need to continue execution and adding new buddies after duplicate-key is detected. That's all what I need. List which I get can be up to 100 records and in theory there can be only few new buddies (so I need to skip all the others (avoiding checks agains db are they already friends))

Comment: Do you commit the transaction (or have auto commit)?

Comment: Auto Commit since I didn't put anything regarding commit rules

Comment: try using connection.setAutoCommit(true); before creating PreparedStatement object

Comment: Don't you have too many unique indexes? Index unique_friend_index prevnts from duplicating data (this is OK), but the last 2 unique indexes id_memb_friend1 and id_memb_friend2 prevent a user from having more than 1 friend. The documentation does not say explicitely what happends if "on duplicate key update" fails on a second constraint but it seems to fail silently. Moreover the doc says In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.